# The Hibernate session (EntityManager) scope in Spring Batch?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-batch

As I’m new to Spring and Spring Batch, I have a general question about Spring Batch and JPA using Hibernate as provider.

Please, I want to know **when** the Hibernate session (wrapped by the EntityManager) **is flushed**? Between Reader, Processor and Writer? or for each commit interval? We can control it or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please, I want to know when the Hibernate session (wrapped by the EntityManager) is flushed? Between Reader, Processor and Writer? or for each commit interval?

The session is flushed after writing a chunk of items, at each commit interval. For more details, take a look at:

- `HibernateItemWriter`: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/item/database/HibernateItemWriter.java#L95
- `JpaItemWriter`: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/item/database/JpaItemWriter.java#L84

> We can control it or not?

If you use the `HibernateItemWriter`, you can set the `clearSession` flag to clear the session after each chunk.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge when the Spring transaction is committed which would be after each chunk.